# Add items based on latest time by maintianing uniqueness: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that look similar to this

```
[ { lastseen: 1640694661000, value: "test1"}, { lastseen: 1640696227000, value: "test2"}]
```

New object that I am trying to insert is

```
{ lastseen: 1640695661564, value: "test1"}
```

I need to push this into a new array based on its recent last seen when the values are same . Only unique values should be present in the final array and that has recent lastseen

The output should look like

```
newArr = [ { lastseen: 1640695661564, value: "test1"}, { lastseen: 1640696227000, value: "test2"} ]
```

In this case test1 with lastseen 1640695661564 is recent and only one such object is present in the final array

Code that I tried

```
function uniqueAndInsert(currArr, input){
   const idx = currArr.findIndex((obj) => {
    obj.lastseen < input.lastseen;
   });
   if(idx!==-1){
      currArr.splice(idx, 0, input);
   }
   else{
     currArr.splice(0);
     currArr.push(input);
   }
   return currArr;
}
```

Comment: You aren't checking if the `value`s are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 cases to handle. 1) `input` is recent than current data (update data) 2) `input` is not recent than current data (no change) 3) `input` does not exist in current data (add data).

```
function uniqueAndInsert(currArr, input) {
  const item = currArr.find(({ value }) => value === input.value);
  if (item && item.lastseen >= input.lastseen) {
    // data is up to date, no changes just return original array
    return currArr;
  }
  // filter the same value data if exist and add input
  return currArr.filter(({ value }) => value !== input.value).concat(input);
}

// alternatively, to do it one iteration
function uniqueAndInsert2(currArr, input) {
  const output = [];
  let exist = false;
  currArr.forEach(({ value, lastseen }) => {
    if (value === input.value) {
      output.push({ value, lastseen: Math.max(input.lastseen, lastseen) });
      exist = true;
    } else {
      output.push({ value, lastseen });
    }
  });
  if (!exist) {
    output.push(input);
  }
  return output;
}
```